# Command to show last modified file, exluding directories

Tags: bash, unix

I am using `ls -t | head -n1` (in the OS X bash shell) to return the last modified file in my working directory. In some cases, a subdirectory of the working file has the most recently modified file in it, so the command returns the name of that subdirectory. How do I write the command to exclude subdirectories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ls -t * | head -1 
works on mine